# mongoDB find documents based on a condition with a value from linked document of another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collections of the following structure:

**objects:**

```
[{"type": "someTypeOne", "menuId": 1},
{"type": "someTypeTwo", "menuId": 1},
{"type": "someTypeOne", "menuId": 2}]
```

**menus:**

```
[{"id":1, "type": "someTypeOne"},
{"id":2, "type": "someTypeOne"}]
```

I need to find all objects where "type" property doesn't match its menus "type". In this case the desired output would be:

```
[{"type": "someTypeTwo", "menuId": 1}]
```

I think that I should use aggregation for this one and I'm fiddling with it at the moment but I was not able to formulate a working query so far.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.objects.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "menus",
            localField: "menuId",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "menu"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$menu"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $ne: [ "$menu.type", "$type" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            menu: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) allows you to get data from both collections, then you can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on `menu` array to get single menu per document and you can apply you inequality condition using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) and [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sGn2Aatlkyt)

Comment: @FIIFE cause it's extremely easy to answer when you clearly define what you need (by examples)